# Cannot connect to Tigase Admin panel?

Tags: server, xmpp, tigase

I am using Tigase XMPP server, Server parameters that I have set are:

Jabber domain name: chat.example.com >> this is public DNS 
Administrator:admin@chat.example.com 
Admin Password: tigase

After installation, I can get access to admin panel by URL: http://localhost:8080/ui/ , but unfortunately I can't login with username and password that I have created during installation process. This makes me really crazy, please help.

Point is that, I can login to the server with android client with above username and pass, also when I delete and reinstall tigase and set the domain to ip address of computer in internal network it's working, but when I use DNS I everything looks good but cannot login to admin environment with username and password.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer at this post:
https://projects.tigase.org/boards/15/topics/6939?r=6942